# Onedrive - download temporarily for preview in Windows Explorer

Tags: onedrive-for-business

In Windows Explorer we have the preview pane. It only works when the file is already present on the local machine and not only in the cloud. This makes it impossible to quickly preview a bunch of files in a cloud-only folder. Opening the file(s) by double clicking or selecting "Keep on this device" works, but is non-productive as then you have to either close the window(s) or selecting "Free up space" afterwards.

How do you force a (temporary) download of files on Sharepoint/Onedrive?

I tried just running a Python script that opens a given file for reading and doesn't do anything with it. Instantly it was downloaded and ready for preview. I have been thinking about making some kind of context menu entry that does exactly that for the selected files, but it seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a batch script and a context menu command instead. It's slower, because it actually reads the file, but it works. I tried just reading the file properties, but they are available without downloading the file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET args=%*
IF NOT DEFINED args GOTO END
ECHO %*
for %%i in (%*\*) do (
    echo %%i
    set /p val=<%%i
)
:END
```

The context menu command is this, if anyone wants to do the same:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Sharepoint Temp Download]
@="&Sharepoint Temp Download"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Sharepoint Temp Download\command]
@="\"C:\\sharepoint_temp_download.bat\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Sharepoint Temp Download]
@="&Sharepoint Temp Download"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Sharepoint Temp Download\command]
@="\"C:\\sharepoint_temp_download.bat\" \"%V\""
```